# Why does my Google App script expect a function to be in a file rather than in the script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I keep getting an error in Google App script when running a function with this variable:

Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot find function getContentAsString in object *file_here*

```
var doc = DriveApp.getFolderById('*FOLDER_ID*');
doc.createFile(file).getContentAsString();
```

Any ideas why? What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: what's the returned object from `doc.createFile(file)`?

Comment: Use the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) to step through each line of code one by one.  Make sure to choose a file name from the drop down list before clicking the bug icon.

Comment: your question misses out the definition of the `file` object you are passing to `doc.createFile(file)`

Answer (score 1):

```
doc.createFile(file).getAs('text/plain').getDataAsString();
```

or

```
doc.createFile(file).getBlob().getDataAsString();
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob

Comment: Both result in the same error. Do you need any further information?

Comment: where is your `file` object defined?